# CodeIgniter view not parsing PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm running into an issue where the following code doesn't parse baseTop.php, but gets it as a literal string instead of parsing the PHP.  The PHP I have on this page such as `<?=$content?>` works fine.  Any thoughts on why this is happening?

```
<?
    $this->load->view('layouts/baseTop.php');
?>
    <div class="shell">
        <div id="header">
            <h1 id="logo" class="fl notext"><a href="/">Home</a></h1>
            <div class="top-bar">
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="sidebar">
            </div>
            <div id="widecolumnWrapper"><div id="widecolumn">
                <!-- tabs -->
                <div id="mainbox">
                    <div class="main-top"><div>&nbsp;</div></div>
                    <div class="main-wrap"><div class="main-cnt">
                    <?=$content?>
                        <span id="mainbox-clear">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div></div>
                    <div class="main-bottom"><div>&nbsp;</div></div>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?
    $this->load->view('layouts/baseBottom.php');
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you don't use short tags?  Use `<?php` to open.

Comment: That fixes it... but I have short tags enabled... why would that make a difference?

Comment: Should get away from using short-tags...

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` to make sure your short open tag option is actually being read as enabled.  I suspect it isn't.  In any case, the short open tags are ambiguous and you shouldn't use them.  They might also be removed in future versions of PHP, but no official deprecation yet.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use short open tags.  Use the full `<?php  ?>`.  If you have short open tags enabled, check `phpinfo()` to verify this setting.  I suspect that your setting isn't set correctly.

You should avoid using short open tags, as they are ambiguous, and may be removed in future versions of PHP.  However, they are not officially deprecated yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't load any views in another view. The reason of error is that `$this` points to `View` class object, and loading views is defined in `CI_Controller` class. To achieve what you want, you could do the following

In controller:

```
$data = $this->load->view('layouts/baseTop.php',array(), TRUE);
$this->load->view('*your view*', array('baseTop'=>$data));
```

In your view: replace `<? $this->load->view('layouts/baseTop.php');?>` with just `<?php echo $baseTop;?>`

So that you'll have another view placed into your view just as if it is included there. Note TRUE in `baseTop.php` loading - this instructs CodeIgniter to catch view output to variable rather than flush it to page.

Comment: Nothing wrong with calling View Class object from within the 'view' state.  I have seen this done in many projects, this could simply be a typo.

Comment: Well, that's some kind of design violation anyway.

Comment: I think you are wrong, read: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Clearly states `A view is simply a web page, or a page fragment, like a header, footer, sidebar, etc. In fact, views can flexibly be embedded within other views (within other views, etc., etc.) if you need this type of hierarchy.`